# Using pre_get_posts to build custom query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been having a time trying to get this to work and looking over everything it seems like it should.

I have a page where I am adding a custom sort function which alters the [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) using [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and set_query_var

In a nutshell I have a few select boxes where users select some things to filter the loop by.  Once a user submits the query for example my url will look like this: http://my-domain.com/gallery/?classroom=&digital_items=&kits_used=26155&project_type=&post_author=

So I added a post with the post meta of kits_used and added a few "kits", check my database for the postmeta and see the meta_value has the array like its supposed to: `a:2:{i:0;s:5:"26155";i:1;s:5:"26152";}`

However, I feel like something is wrong with my pre_get_posts function because when I choose the kit with the id of 26155, it says no posts are found.  Not sure if I am doing it correctly because its an array or if Im missing something else here.

My function:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'gallery_sort_query');

function gallery_sort_query( $query )
{
// validate
    if( is_admin() )
    {
        return;
    }

    if( !$query->is_main_query() )
    {
        return;
    }

// get original meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

    // allow the url to alter the query
    if( !empty($_GET['kits_used']) )
    {
        $kits_used = explode(',', $_GET['kits_used']);

        //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'kits_used',
            'value'     => $kits_used,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
            );
    }

    if( !empty($_GET['project_type']) )
    {
        $project_type = explode(',', $_GET['project_type']);

        //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'project_type',
            'value'     => $project_type,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
            );
    }

    if( !empty($_GET['digital_items']) )
    {
        $digital_items = explode(',', $_GET['digital_items']);

        //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'digital_items',
            'value'     => $digital_items,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
            );
    }

    if( !empty($_GET['classroom']) )
    {
        $classroom = explode(',', $_GET['classroom']);

        //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'classroom',
            'value'     => $classroom,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
            );
    }

    if( !empty($_GET['post_author']) )
    {
        $author = $_GET['post_author'];



        $query->set( 'author' , $author );

    }

// update the meta query args
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

// always return
    return;

}
```

Could really use some help here in case I am missing something, everything looks like it is lining up but for some reason it still isnt working except for the "Author" sort drop down.  Hopefully I have given too much info rather than not enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for something like this I found the answer.  Because the meta values are stored as an array in the database, I needed to use LIKE for compare on those particular queries.

Here is the full working function, note where I use LIKE instead of IN for the meta_values that are an array.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'gallery_sort_query');

function gallery_sort_query( $query )
{
// validate
    if( is_admin() )
    {
        return;
    }

    if( !$query->is_main_query() )
    {
        return;
    }

// get original meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

    // allow the url to alter the query
    if( !empty($_GET['kits_used']) )
    {
        $kits_used = explode(',', $_GET['kits_used']);

        //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'kits_used',
            'value'     => $kits_used,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            );
    }

    if( !empty($_GET['project_type']) )
    {
        $project_type = explode(',', $_GET['project_type']);

        //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'project_type',
            'value'     => $project_type,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
            );
    }

    if( !empty($_GET['digital_items']) )
    {
        $digital_items = explode(',', $_GET['digital_items']);

        //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'digital_items',
            'value'     => $digital_items,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            );
    }

    if( !empty($_GET['classroom']) )
    {
        $classroom = explode(',', $_GET['classroom']);

        //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'classroom',
            'value'     => $classroom,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
            );
    }

    if( !empty($_GET['post_author']) )
    {
        $author = $_GET['post_author'];



        $query->set( 'author' , $author );

    }

// update the meta query args
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

// always return
    return;

}
```